# Render template can not find file

Tags: python, flask

Hello i am new to Flask and render_template can not find my file

```
from re import template
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

now = datetime.now()
date_time= now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # content = "<p> The time is now" + date_time + "</p>"
    content = render_template("templates/index.html")
    return content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

this is my code and my folder structure is

```
flask
 |-- pycache
 |-- app.py
 |-- templates
      |--index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

Good question. Template paths exclude the "templates/" directory prefix.

Just change `render_template("templates/index.html")` to `render_template("index.html")`

```py
from re import template
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

now = datetime.now()
date_time= now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # content = "<p> The time is now" + date_time + "</p>"
    content = render_template("index.html")
    return content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```